# Qatar Flight ticket name change

Tags: air-travel, tickets, qatar

My Son name on his passport is: First Name: XXX YYY Last Name: ZZZ

The name which I gave in the flight ticket is First name: XXX ZZZ Last name: ZZZ It's a Qatar ticket from US to India. Will there be any problem while traveling? My Son's age is 13 Years.

Comment: Probably not. Call Qatar and ask